# Spark Streaming not executing the lines of code within foreach

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Quick question on Spark Streaming.

I am initialising createDirectStream from KafkaUtils as stream and saving it as InputDStream in spark-streaming, as below.

```
val stream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      context,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topicList, KafkaParameters)
    )

  stream
      .foreachRDD { rdd =>
        println("Executing within rdd")
        val rddSize = rdd.count()
        if (rddSize > 0) { println(s"Received data $rddSize") }
        else {println("Not received any data")}
      }

  context.start()
```

I am able to see the output for the produced data for almost 50 mins. After 50 mins, I can see below messages in logs,

```
Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_name-partition_number
Resetting offset for partition topic_name-partition_number to offset 12908.
```

but no more logs saying "Executing within rdd" or "Received data $rddSize" or "Not received any data"

The whole logic is working fine when I am starting the consumer but after sometime it just stops working. Any idea on what's going on here?

Comment: The behavior you're describing, where the Kafka consumer seems to stop processing after some time, could have several potential causes.

Comment: @diniramdhni, Can you please quote the potential causes?

Comment: The issue could be due to factors such as offset resetting, slow data arrival, lengthy batch intervals, overwhelming data volume, resource limitations, unhandled errors, inability to restart the context, incorrect log levels, lack of monitoring, or certain timeouts triggering a halt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not shown `KafkaParameters`, but any Kafka consumer defaults to set `auto.offset.reset=latest`, meaning the offset where there is nothing to consume. And as your logs say, the consumer is resetting and seeking again to the end of the topic. You need an actively running producer to see any data with that config

Also, *Spark Streaming* (this is not [Kafka Steams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)) is deprecated and all features of Spark Structured Streaming work similarly, at least for Kafka.

Comment: I tried debugging further where the stream of received/consumed data from the topic is internally converting to a job by JobGenerator and scheduled by JobScheduler. I couldn't find any error logs where it says something failed. From the moment I am seeing issue, jobs are generated but are not scheduled.
And there are no logs around this to understand why the kafka stopped to schedule the jobs. Any pointers to this?
Is there a way to know the start point file/line for createDirectStream in kafka Utils?

Comment: Not scheduled? The Spark UI (or YARN, if you're using that) would tell you why, most commonly there's not enough resources in the cluster. The Spark master / YARN ResourceManager is where logs would be for this, not your app... Kafka doesn't schedule itself. Regarding starting point, as mentioned, check your `auto.offset.reset` config

Comment: Yup, got it. Had to check in Executor Logs.

Comment: Adding some more info, Kafka streaming is internally using Spark Streaming where all the consumed data is taken as a small batch and spark streaming generated jobs for this, generated jobs are scheduled onto Executors post which notification of job start will be sent to way back to Driver.

Comment: No, Kafka Streams does not use any Spark code. That's backwards... Spark Streaming uses KafkaConsumer, not Kafka Streams